# HTTPS migration

Tags: html, css, https, web-hosting

I recently migrated a website to HTTPS using an AutoSSL tool on bluehost. I see some distortions in the content like missing background colors, table displacements, missing_logos etc.

Does anyone know how styling can get effected with HTTPS migration effect?

Comment: The short answer is no. But, you may want to revisit all your static content and make sure they are served using https too. Maybe you have some style sheets breaking.

Comment: Do you see anything in the browser console? If content is getting blocked due to loading over HTTP, I'd expect you'd see a warning / error there.

Comment: Yup, that's the case, I did change all of them. But few of them still don't load an image is throwing 404 error, saying can't load the resource.

Comment: Sry, its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you access a website using HTTPS, the browser will block resource requests using HTTP. You should load all resources securely over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit .htaccess file. And to migrate your traffic from HTTP to HTTPS, you require a redirect rule.

So, it's obvious to use .htaccess. I hope you know how to edit such a file.

I will  suggest you  check this Article [How to Force SSL and Manage the non-SSL Page Using cPanel](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-force-ssl-and-manage-the-non-ssl-page-using-cpanel/)